# Disappearing voltage

Tags: voltage, power-engineering

I'm an 30 yr electrician. I have a problem neither I nor my co workers have ever seen nor can we find an answer to. Here's the situation.
In a particular 60' length of EMT, (metallic conduit), we had several circuits run. The load for one of the circuits was not working, we measured voltage at the load and the voltage was zero, measured at source and had 277vac. Somewhere in a pipe of 60' with no junctions or splices the voltage disappeared. Here's the best part we replaced the conductor with same result. We then added a conductor tied it in in parallel to the conductor with disappearing voltage and had full 277vac at the end, load lighting now working. Only one wire still had voltage. If we removed the parallel conductor voltage disappears. If we pulled the conductor out of the conduit laid it on the ground it would then carry the voltage. put back in conduit and no voltage at end.

Summary of details:

- *System voltage- 277/480Y 3ph/4wire grounded.
- All conductors- #12 thhn copper
- All conductors passed continuity test.
- Circuit in question= 1 ungrounded ("hot") & 1 grounded (neutral). (2 wire)
- Multiple other 2wire 277v circuits in conduit of diverse phasing,(no problems that we knew of).
- All circuits terminated to 20amp breakers.
- Conduit mechanical continuity was checked, no loose parts or joints.
- Conduit on metal rack connected to steel structure, with several other metal conduits.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: could we see picure(s) of the installation points or points of interest? (beggining/middle/end of cable(s))?

Comment: It really sounds as if something was just incorrectly wired. Though regarding "All conductors passed continuity test" - what about shorts between conductors?

Comment: Maybe it's acting like a transmission line and the conductor is just the right length that you're measuring the voltage at a null. I've seen some pretty strange things happen from resonance, such as a plumber's van where the 100W two way radio's output power would drop to almost nothing when they had pipe stored in a PVC tube on the roof. Pull the pipes out, worked fine, put them in, it was like they sucked all the power right out of the antenna. Pipes were just the right length to be resonant at the radio's frequency. Sounds crazy, but sometimes crazy stuff happens.

Comment: Did you carefully check the wire for punctures? Could it be that something spiky punctured the insulation and shorted to the metal conduit? Or a faulty isolation with cracks and humidity in the conduit? Can you measure the current on the end where voltage is present?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're experiencing some sort of electrical interference that is causing the voltage to drop in the conduit. There could be a variety of causes, such as high levels of electromagnetic interference (EMI) or radio frequency interference (RFI) in the vicinity, or electrical interference from other conductors in the same conduit or nearby. The fact that adding a parallel conductor resolved the problem suggests that the issue is not with the conductor itself, but rather with the environment in which it is installed. I would recommend further investigation into the source of the interference, such as checking for high levels of EMI/RFI in the area, or performing a test to determine if there is electrical interference from other conductors in the vicinity.

I also suggest:

-Look for heavy equipment that is used at the location (heavy motors from close buildings).

-Try checking your installation at different times (at night maybe) the source of EMI noise might be gone at that time.

-Try using oscilloscope to see the input and output of your cable's supply. Even use spectrum analyzer if you can/have one. (Actually the spectrum analyzer should be the first one to suggest here. But its the most expensive option. You can find cheap hobbyist spectrum analyzers as well though.)

I have heard such strong EMI interferences happen, which were so strong that could run 220V motors that pumped water from lakes. (Yes this was a particular case/example I heard happened somewhere in Russia at the Soviet era)

Comment: I think it sounds very far-fetched to blame EMI for this. Some 277VAC voltage doesn't disappear in thin air because of EMI.

Comment: @Lundin well I placed my bet there. OP mentioned his age and I assume experienced colleagues as well so I mentioned the most rare and unthinkable case I could think of.

Answer (score 0):

If the wires themselves show continuity, then it's most likely that there's something wrong with the connections at one end.  Maybe a broken or high resistance joint.  Maybe the three phases and neutral haven't been wired to the right connections at one end.